# Tools to convert CANopen raw data using *.dbc file?

Tags: python, r, canopen

I'm pretty new with CANopen, and also a little bit shooting in the dark... 
I would like to know if there are tools or packages in R or Python to convert raw data logged from a CANopen device, to human readable values, with a *.dbc file? 
Does someone have experience with this?
In advance thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like cantools might do the trick:

https://pypi.org/project/cantools/

It can decode CAN data using a DBC file. For actually reading the CAN bus it integrates with python-can.

https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html#

To read CAN data from a log file there's a module in python-can for that

https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/listeners.html

And finally if you want to interact directly with a live CANopen bus there's the CANopen for Python library

https://canopen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/