# CANopen bus data translation/mapping with .eds/.dcf files on Linux Terminal Window

Tags: canopen

For CAN bus, data in a terminal window e.g. coming from CANplayer (CANutils), can be mapped/translated with the command:

```
candump vcan0 | cantools decode --single-line '/home/xyz.dbc'
```

Is there a similar solution for CANopen bus?
Having tried:

(1) canopen-monitor -i vcan0
somehow the *.eds file(s) in the relative subdirectory /.cache/canopen-monitor are not applied.

(2) With jupyter notebooks (if this can be avoided, it would better) there is a somehow solution:

```
import canopen
network = canopen.Network()
node = network.add_node(0x1a, 'abc.eds')
network.connect(bustype='socketcan', channel='vcan0')
node.object_dictionary[0x2001][1].__dict__
```

What i am looking for is a solution that all:

- SDO CANopen Data in the bus is mapped to the explanation in the eds file (s). (right now a file for one node would be a good start)
- with the decimal/string realtime value.

Comment: I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270178/tools-to-convert-canopen-raw-data-using-dbc-file
Unfortunately its not a solution.

Comment: What i found is a video: 
CANopen Magic: Get Symbols from EDS. 
Its only available under Windows and therefore the CANopen, CAN features under Linux like CANplayer, CANsend are not that easy available.